# How to convert html table columns to table rows, dom object, php

Tags: php, dom

I've an html table and i want to convert its columns to rows. Columns can contain plan text, form elements(input, select, checkbox), or html tags(span, div). Consider the following html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
        <td>Cell 5</td>
        <td>Cell 6</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

after dom operation i need the following:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 6</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

```
$rows = $xpath->query('xpath to table/tr');
foreach ($rows as $row){
    $cols = $xpath->query('xpath to table/tr/*');
    $row->parentNode->removeChild($row);
    foreach ($cols as $col){
        $newNode = $this->createElement('tr');
        $newNode->appendChild($col);
        $node->appendChild($newNode);
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

its working fine, but its adding empty rows:

```
<table>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Any idea whats am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You can parse HTML and XML with DOM, this is how you could read a table:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $table );
$tds = array();
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'td' ) as $td ) {
  $tds[] = $td->nodeValue;
}
```

To print the structure flattened:

```
foreach($tds as $td){
    print '<td>'.$td.'</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move each `<td>` element into a new `<tr>` child of it's current ancestor `<table>` element:

```
foreach($xpath->query('//td') as $td)
    $xpath->query('ancestor::table[1]', $td)->item(0)
        ->appendChild($doc->createElement('tr'))->appendChild($td);
{{;;}}
```

Afterwards you can remove all `<tr>` elements that do not have any `<td>` children any longer:

```
foreach($xpath->query('//tr[0 = count(td)]') as $tr)
    $tr->parentNode->removeChild($tr);
{{;;}}
```

Your document has now been transformed:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Cell 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell 4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell 5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cell 6</td></tr>
</table>
```